# Swift - Is this code wrong or should I use UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, nsuserdefaults

I have an app which is connected to Firebase and you can login using Google and Facebook. The app has a home screen which is loaded when the user is signed in. I don't want to show the login screen if the user has already signed in before. So I use this code in the home screen to check if the user is signed in. Home screen is the initial view controller in the app

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil{
        // user is signed in
    }else{
        // No user is signed in.
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

This code works very well. I know, that I could use UserDefaults too, but this seems to be an easier way. Is it wrong or should I use UserDefaults?

But the only problem with that is, for a quick moment the home screen is shown and then the segue is performed to the login screen, and I guess it's because it's in the viewdidApepar method, so the code gets executed after the viewcontroller appeared. Do you know a solution to it?

Comment: I'm sure, that Firebase uses UserDefaults or CoreData underneath of this API. I use the same way, never had any issues.

Comment: Yes but the only problem with that is for a quick moment the home screen is shown and then the segue is performed to the login screen, and I guess it's because it's in the viewdidApepar method, so the code gets executed after the viewcontroller appeared. Do you know a solution to it?

Comment: Using `viewWillAppear` instead might work

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: @MartonZeisler What happens in case of using `viewWillAppear` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I do personally, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.

```
    if UserManager.sharedManager.currentUser != nil {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    } else {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    }
```

Of course I have a UserManager which handles if the user is logged in or not.(UserManager:NSObject)

```
var currentUser: User? {
    return User.unarchiveStoredUser()
}
```

User is stored with decoder into UserDefautls then unarchived to verify if a user is logged in or not (User :NSObject)

```
func archiveUser() {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "userIdentifier")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

class func unarchiveStoredUser() -> User? {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userIdentifier") as? Data {
        let user = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! User
        return user
    }
    return nil
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Where should I put your second code section about the currentUser?

Comment: Also, your third code section is in a class called UserManager?

Comment: In the app delegate, it says UserManager has no member  sharedManager

Comment: lol u can't copy and paste the code directly, theres a Singleton in between (sharedManager)

Comment: I don't understand it, so what should I do?

Comment: If u can't understand the code above you're better off using the method your using already, my method is pretty simple, but you need to know how to handle managers > services and singletons.

Long explanation short, when I log a user in I copyFromJSON into a User object (which also contains the archive and unarchive user) then I use the UserManager and the singleton to call whatever I need from the user, whether its log in status or his name, email, etc.

Comment: Go read about encoding, singletons, decoders, etc, then this code above will help you 100% in your issue.